# Visual studio 2008 adding existing project to main solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a main visual studio solution and other solution.(VS 2008) I want to add a project from other solution. If I use "Add Existing Item" visual studio create a reference to that project from main solution but it does not physically add files to solution folder.

```
How can i make physically add other project to my main solution ?
```

PS: physically MEANS the other project became first class memeber of my solution...Physically exist in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what your problem is, how about FIRST copying the files into the solution directory, THEN adding the project reference...?

You seem to be complaining that VS is not copying all files from the referenced source project into the new solution, but that's exactly how VS works. It does not "clone" a project when adding it to a solution - it is always only a "reference".

Comment: Yes you are right...It is so simple...Just copy physical directory, then add reference...Thanks for yor answer

Answer (score 3):

File > Add > Existing Project.

Answer (score 1):

Projects only ever exist as references in a Solution file. (Crack a solution file open in notepad sometime and see for yourself.)

The whole point of Microsoft's Solution/Project paradigm is that your projects can live wherever you choose and still be tied together in a Solution file.